# What does the at-sign @ mean in the bash command: date --date @...?

Tags: bash

Searching the internet I found explanations only for '$@', meaning 'expand to positional parameters'. But I couldn't find anything about the @ sign by itself.

I stumbled over it in the third snipped of the accepted answer to this question:
https://superuser.com/questions/611538/is-there-a-way-to-display-a-countdown-or-stopwatch-timer-in-a-terminal

Specifically:

```
date -u --date @$((`date +%s` - $date1)) +%H:%M:%S
```

Comment: Questions that are incomplete without content behind a link need to have enough of a a quotation from behind that link to be understood and answered even if the content behind that link changes or dies -- just the same as how we don't accept answers relying on links unless they directly quote enough to be useful and understood even if the link dies.

Comment: Thank you for the addition, but i'm not quite happy with the change ot the topic, because it doesn't reflect my misunderstanding anymore of the @-sign being a bash element. The question doesn't really make sense anymore with this topic.

Comment: Is this better? I'm trying to arrive at something accurately reflects the actual problem in such a way that someone with the same problem would find it, but that doesn't imply behaviour/semantics that don't actually exist to folks just looking at questions by title, and that doesn't draw folks curious about obscure shell syntax and features in just to be disappointed.

Comment: (Incidentally, there actually *is* other bash syntax that uses the @ symbol, in extglobs; someone just seeing the original title could expect the question to be about them).

Comment: Thanks, i'm ok with that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the context you show, the `@` is in the beginning of the `--date` argument to the `date` command:

```
date -u --date @$((`date +%s` - $date1)) +%H:%M:%S
```

In that case it means that the argument should be treated as the number of seconds since epoch, see an example in `man date`:

> Convert seconds since the epoch (1970-01-01 UTC) to a date
>
> ```
> $ date --date='@2147483647'
> ```

or:

```
$ date -u -d @0
Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 UTC 1970
```

This meaning of `@` is defined by the `date` utility alone and not by `bash`.

Answer (score 4):

Came here looking for the same thing as OP. Haven't found an answer yet but just in case someone else finds it useful, the `@` symbol can also be used with curl to send a raw bytestream via a file:

```bash
curl http://my.domain.com --data-binary @file.dat
```